# Integrate cassandra and PHP

Tags: php, cassandra

I didn't find any links for integration between cassandra and php.
Help me ,I am very much new to integration
 http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/ but it is not correct probably.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO

Comment: The link you posted above is right, perhaps have a look at the quick start part of the guide? http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/#quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastax academy has a getting started course for [PHP](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-php).

Also, there is a demo application [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcassandra/files/) with PHP and Cassandra integration